# Upload and download of images,video to firebase storage to/from android app is too slow

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am developing an android application which includes photos and videos upload/downloads to firebase storage. I am very happy with the firebase features, but uploading/downloading image and video taking little more time, even though I am on the high-speed internet.

Upload and Download of image and videos work perfectly, But I can't expect the slowness from a Google-backed platform. I am compressing the image before upload even though, the time taken is more. say for eg. I uploaded 7Mb size image on WhatsApp profile pic it will be done in max 5-6 seconds. But the same image upload will take more than 60 seconds in my android app.

Guys, if you have any better solutions or any implementation from your end Please share it.

Regards,
Srini

Comment: the speed of upload depends on the size, quality and compression of image and up rate speed of your internet bandwidth (upstream)
i think you should try resizing and/or compressing the image.

Comment: according to me you have to upload only urls on firebase, you have to upload your large files on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about media compression. 
You can also upload image, video and other media file same as WhatsApp by compressing you media.
after compression check speed of firebase for upload and download. you will also feel the speed of it.

Here is the tools for compression

- Image: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor
- Video: https://github.com/fishwjy/VideoCompressor

and many more.
I'm using this two libs for compress video and image files.

Use firebase upload this way.

```
File file =new File(mediaPath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file),metadata);
            Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return riversRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    getUploadedMediaPath.getUploadedFileUrl(downloadUri.toString());
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I have included image and media compression in my code before upload. files are getting compressed to 1:10 ratio before upload, example 7 MB image is compressed and stored in firebase storage to some 70KB image. Image quality is also fine. But I am not able to understand why this is taking more than 60 seconds.

Comment: still it's taking same time?

Comment: yes.I would like to know is it okay to use Firebase for photo and image sharing android applications. Because i searched a lot and dint find any solution for it. Many people quoting image/video upload and download is slow using firebase storage.

Comment: please check my updated answer. hope it may help you. it's faster for me. I'm using same function for upload Image, Video and Audio files.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried the same way and have included image compression before upload..Image compression is also working fine..everything is fine except some little extra time taken for upload.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried check out WebP and WebM for photo and video?

It's a format developed by some team at Google in aiming to reduce file sizes to minimal as it be without altering the quality of the files massively. The results are quiet good compares to other format of images and videos. WebP also support encoder and decoder.

Check out the tools here WebP :

> https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

Just download the tool and have it in your working folder, invoke command prompt and run

> cwebp -q int fileName.jpg -o fileName.webp

and see the result.

Check out the tools for WebM:

> https://www.webmproject.org/